# Youtube: Stream searched videos on Java

Tags: java, youtube, video-streaming, youtube-api

I am trying to make a search on youtube via Youtube API for Java.
I want to Play these videos "by any means of playing".
How can i do this?In many cases i have seen the example:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoid")));
```

How can i use this?Do i need to add any more jar files?
Or something else is needed?

Comment: Is this for an Android application?

Comment: @JeffPosnick nope,not for Android application

Answer (score 0):

The supported means of playing back YouTube videos are described at https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#player_apis

If you're writing a desktop Java application, then you're going to need to find some way to embed a web browser in your application and use an embedded player, or perhaps just force a separate browser instance to open with a `http://youtu.be/VIDEO_ID` URL.

Comment: i don't want a web browser, but `JMF` or some related API will work.